# List most recent mercurial hashes

Tags: bash, mercurial

Does `hg` have a nice way to list just the hashes of the most recent commits in the repo on separate lines? `hg id -i` only gives me the current commit.

Something equivalent to the `-l` parameter in `hg log` such that I could do something like:

```
$ hg id -i -l 3
1eb0c5a3002e  <--- youngest commit
321c6693361e  <--- 2nd youngest commit
647724838c03  <--- 3rd youngest commit
```

---

To give some context, I have a bash script which I pass a mercurial hash to and it builds a docker image,

```
./build_image.sh 647724838c03
```

I am trying to get command line completion for the hash argument so I need a command to generate all the hashes which I can drop into `compgen`:

```
local HASHES=$(cd $REPO && hg id -i -l 10)
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$HASHES" -- $cur) )
```

Most of the time the hash I'm wanting to build will be the checked out commit so `hg id -i` will work okay, but getting a full list of the last 10 hashes would be nice!

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

**EDIT**

I got a work around using `grep` and `awk`:

```
$ hg log -l 5 | grep changeset | awk -vn=12 '{print substr($0,length($0)-n+1)}'
1eb0c5a3002e
ec0db890a6c3
321c6693361e
4a1e2ca2df06
2d1ef7d57485
```

This isn't great though:

- makes assumptions about how `hg log` outputs (which might change in different versions)
- that awk command is a bit too mystical for me :)
- doesn't work for Windows (assuming you're trying to solve a different problem to bash tab completion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what you have log for. Template the output to your needs, e.g.

```
hg log -l10 --template="{node|short} {date} {author}\n"
```

gives you output like

```
0c4520bbf388 2017-06-07 12:25 +0200 username <user@example.com>
```

Checkout `hg help template` for more templating options. You can basically apply templating to all relevant commands which generate  these kind of outputs.

Mind: if you do not sort log explicitly by commit date, it will return you the 10 newest commits in your repository - which does not necessarily reflect order of commit time. You can do that by giving additionally a revset and sorting by it:

```
hg log --rev="sort(date('<now'))" --template="{node}\n" -l5
```